# docker-compose not run well if set on a job's shell command with jenkins

Tags: ubuntu, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, docker-machine

I installed Jenkins on Ubuntu. Added current user to docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

Also added `jenkins` user to docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

I set this shell command in a Jenkins job:

```
#!/bin/sh

docker-compose up -d --build
```

Got these console output from Jenkins after ran that job:

```
...
$ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins1207165068215188667.sh
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

But if I try the command `docker-compose up -d --build` on the host under `jenkins` user, it works. Why can't work use Jenkins' shell command?

And, why it let me to use `docker-machine`? I tried to create a docker machine, but the default driver is `virtualbox`. Since I am using Ubuntu without GUI, I think the `virtualbox` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the DOCKER_HOST env var? That is more or less what `docker-machine use ...` does. You need to tell docker what socket to connect to, and possibly there is some .bashrc or similar that runs when you log in under jenkins that sets that? Check DOCKER_HOST var before you run `docker-compose up -d` as jenkins and see what the value is. Then you can `export DOCKER_HOST=...` in your script when you know that.

Comment: I checked my env that there isn't any `DOCKER_HOST` exist. I added it: `DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock` to job's shell command. Also tried to export it on the host like `export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. All of them are the same result, same error.

Comment: Do you see a DOCKER_HOST value when you're logged in as jenkins and can run docker-compose up successfully?

Comment: Also, the DOCKER_HOST should be set to a tcp address. Try `export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"`

Comment: Also you might like to try restarting the jenkins slave process: `systemctl restart jenkins-slave`

Comment: I can't see a `DOCKER_HOST` value when I logged in as jenkins user. But I can run `docker-compose up` successfully under that user.

Comment: Then please see the other suggestion to restart the jenkins slave process.

Comment: I am using only one Jenkins server now. There isn't `jenkins-slave` yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171207/discussion-between-see-sharper-and-v-v).

Comment: @seesharper @v v Can one of you explain in the answer how you solved this problem?